# Javascript not catching error using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, fetch

I have an authService which has the following fetch

```
export const handleForm = () => {

    return fetch('http://localhost:5000/login')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Email or password incorrect");
            } else {
                return response.json();
            }
        })
        .then(json => json)
        .catch(error => error);
};
```

I'm calling the method from my controller:

```
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    handleForm(e)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            //setAuthenticatedUser(response);
            // setDomUser(response.user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            document.querySelector('#error').innerHTML = error;
        })
};
```

I've tried a few things to get the error in my catch, in the controller
But I keep getting the response callback fired.
**The error from my authService isn't being caught**

#### I've Tried

- throw new Error();
- Promise.reject();

Comment: That's it. How could i've missed that? Care to make an answer, and explain, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`Promise.prototype.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch):

> ## Syntax Section
>
> ```
> p.catch(onRejected);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **The Promise returned by `catch()` is rejected if `onRejected` throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved.**

Using `.catch(error => error)` as a callback *returns* the exception. So it neither "throws an error" nor "returns a Promise which is itself rejected". The promise returned by it is thus resolved, not rejected.

Simply remove `.catch(error => error)` and it will work. And when you're at it, also remove `.then(json => json)` as it is useless.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this. What If I kept the catch() block, just for learning purposed, how should I 'refactor' it so it does get catched?

Comment: @Notflip Check the (examples from the) link

Comment: @Notflip `catch(e => {throw e})` or `catch(e => Promise.reject(e))`.